# Let $f_X(x)= \frac{x^2e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi} } 1_{(-\infty,+\infty)}$, what is this distribution called?

Tags: distributions, density-function, distribution-identification

Let $$f_X(x)= \frac{x^2e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi} } 1_{(-\infty,+\infty)},$$
is the pdf of random variable $X$. What is this distribution called?

I only know $f_X(x)\propto x^2e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}  1_{(0,+\infty)}$ is the pdf of chi distribution with $3$ degree of freedom.

Comment: A common nomenclature for such constructs where a known distribution with positive support is reflected around the origin is to call the new distribution a Reflected XXX. So, Reflected Chi in your case. Similarly, Reflected Weibull, Reflected Gamma etc

Comment: @wolfies, Reflected Chi  or Double Chi (according to the first answer)? which one is a better?

Answer (score 1):

Well, in very much the same way that you can symmetrize an exponential pdf to obtain a Laplace distribution:
$$\mathrm{Lap}(x;\, b) = \begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{2}\mathrm{Exp}(x;\,\dfrac{1}{b})\quad\text{if}\;x \geq 0\\
\dfrac{1}{2}\mathrm{Exp}(-x;\, \dfrac{1}{b})\quad\text{if}\;x < 0
\end{cases}$$
you can symmetrize a chi distribution by using the same technique
$$\mathrm{DoubleChi}(x;\, k) = \begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{2}\,\chi(x;\, k)\quad\text{if}\;x \geq 0\\
\dfrac{1}{2}\,\chi(-x;\, k)\quad\text{if}\;x < 0
\end{cases}$$
I'm not sure it's a very important distribution, however, you have that if $X\sim \mathrm{DoubleChi}_k$ then $\lvert X \rvert \sim\chi_k$.

**For reference:** Scipy calls this pdf the "double weibull", [see the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.dweibull.html#scipy.stats.dweibull) for more details.